# WPF Binding to items within a dictionary by key

Tags: c#, dictionary, binding

What I want it to bind TextBoxes to my dictionaries values.
I could find some posts about it already but :

One means having my dictionary as context :

XML :

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstLine" Text="{Binding Path=[FirstLine]}"/>
```

XAML :

```
public ImportProfilesOptions()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    contexte = new ViewModelImportProfilesOptions();
    DataContext = contexte.ParamsData;

}
```

The other one [using Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264180/binding-with-dictionary-item-by-key) :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="dictionaryItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding dictionary}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But I would like to use it, without using Templates (I need to add in labels some translates I take from properties), and without setting my dictionary as context. Something like that :

XML

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstLine" Text="{Binding Path=ParamsDate[FirstLine]}" />
```

XAML

```
contexte = new ViewModelImportProfilesOptions();
DataContext = contexte;
```

But then, binding is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box, though you could create your own converter I guess:

```
public class SomeFunkyConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (!(value is Dictionary<string,string> dictionary))
         return null;

      if (!(parameter is string key))
         return null;

      return !dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var result) ? null : result;
   }
   
   // ill leave this up to you
   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**Usage**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ParamsDate, 
                          ElementName=TextBox, 
                          Converter={StaticResource SomeFunkyConverter},
                          ConverterParameter='Bob'}"/>
```

<sub>***Note** : Completely untested*</sub>

Comment: why "sanity aside"? isn't it correct to try access a dictionary through binding?

Comment: @Siegfried.V i just add that as a disclaimer :)